# Codename One: Connecting and populating a drop-down menu with an SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, drop-down-menu, codenameone

I am trying to connect an SQLite database file to a picker component (accepting strings). This should act similar to a drop-down menu. I have tried to follow previous advice and examples, but without success.

As indicated in a previous post, I have saved the database file in the source folder of the application. [View of the source folder where I have saved the database file (highlighted).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adkIY.jpg)

The code I have used to implement my app is as follows with the below layout.

//-----------------------

database code

//-----------------------

```
public class MyApplication {

private Form current;
private Resources theme;

public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
    // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
}

private Container Home() {
    Container home = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    return home;
}

private Container AddItem() {
    Container addItem = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    TextArea item = new TextArea("Add Item");
    addItem.addComponent(item);
    Picker selectItem = new Picker();
    selectItem.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------        

Database db = null;
Cursor cur = null;
try {
    db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("FoodAndBeverage.db");
    if(selectItem.getText().startsWith("Still Water")) {
        cur = db.executeQuery(selectItem.getText());
        int columns = cur.getColumnCount();
        addItem.removeAll();
        if(columns > 0) {
            boolean next = cur.next();
            if(next) {
                ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
                String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                    columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                }
                while(next) {
                    Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                    String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                        currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                    }
                    data.add(currentRowArray);
                    next = cur.next();
                }
                Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                data.toArray(arr);
                addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, arr)));
            } else {
                addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
            }
        } else {
            addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
        }
    } else {
        db.execute(selectItem.getText());
        addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query completed successfully");
    }
    addItem.revalidate();
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
    addItem.removeAll();
    addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Error: " + err);
    addItem.revalidate();
} finally {
    Util.cleanup(db);
    Util.cleanup(cur);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    addItem.addComponent(selectItem);
    TextField quantity = new TextField("", "Quantity (ml or g)", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
    addItem.addComponent(quantity);
    Button add = new Button("Add");
    addItem.addComponent(add);
    TextArea results = new TextArea("Results");
    addItem.addComponent(results);
    return addItem;
}

private Container Settings() {
    Container settings = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));     
    TextArea nutrients = new TextArea("Target");
    settings.addComponent(nutrients);
    TextField volume = new TextField("", "Volume (ml)", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
    settings.addComponent(volume);
    TextArea duration = new TextArea("Hydration Duration");
    settings.addComponent(duration);
    settings.add("Start:");
    Picker start = new Picker();
    start.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
    settings.addComponent(start);
    settings.add("End:");
    Picker end = new Picker();
    end.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
    settings.addComponent(end);       
    Button save = new Button("Save");
    settings.addComponent(save);
    return settings;
}

public void start() {
    if(current != null)
    {
      current.show();
      return;
    }

    Form home = new Form("Hydrate", new BorderLayout());
    Tabs t = new Tabs();
    t.addTab("Home", Home());
    t.addTab("Intake", AddItem());
    t.addTab("Settings", Settings());
    home.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, t);
    home.show();

}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}

}
```

I would therefore appreciate any advice and guidance on exactly where I am going wrong and how to implement the suggested changes in my code.

Comment: I used `String ... getDatabasePath("FoodAndBeverage.db/Items")` instead of the `openOrCreate()` method. This sorted my SQLite connection issue (I think), but still does not populate the picker. This may be due to `if(selectItem.getText().startsWith("Still Water"))` as it refers to the name of the picker component. I would therefore appreciate any advice and guidance on how this could be implemented in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the file under src does indeed end with the extension `db` as the Windows hidden extensions nonsense is turned on.

This code will **NOT** open a db placed in src:

```
db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("FoodAndBeverage.db");
```

You need to do something like this to implicitly initialize the DB the first time the app is installed:

```
String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("FoodAndBeverage.db");
FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
if(!fs.exists(path)) {
    try (InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/FoodAndBeverage.db");
            OutputStream os = fs.openOutputStream(path)) {
        Util.copy(is, os);
    } catch(IOException err) {
            Log.e(err);
    }
}
db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("FoodAndBeverage.db");
```

Notice that the code above doesn't check for updates of the DB so assuming the DB is read only you might want to update/merge it with app updates.

Answer (score 0):

The above code doesn't work on Android device, this works only on simulator. I have tested multiple times in the android device. In the real android device ,the database is not loaded at all, shows **sql exception error**

> "No such table sql exception".

Looks like *preloaded sqlite .db* file is never tested on real Android device.